# New Brakes and Rotors... but still grinding sound

Tags: toyota, brakes, brake-rotor, 4wd, grinding

So I have a 91 Toyota pickup, 4wd and 4 cyl-22r engine. I just replaced the rotors and brake pads and bled the system. When I went to drive it after the install, I got about 300 feet away from my house and heard grinding after I began to brake. Turned around, went back to the house and heard grinding not just while braking, but also when regular driving and coasting. My initial thought was bearings, but when I checked them during the install they looked fine to me, they did have a small amount of brown on them, but I attributed that to grease. Any ideas?

Comment: Well on the bright side, it's probably only 1 wheel, and it sounds like the brakes. I'd try jacking them each up and trying moving them by hand.

Comment: Brake dust shield scraping?